# Android apply settings after setContentView

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I have an application, using the `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration cfg)`. I also set the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`. So the `onConfigChanged()` method is called, and because I have the `layout-land` and `layout-port` directories with layouts for both orientations, I have a piece of code looking like this:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration cfg) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(cfg);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    controller.applySettingsToButtons();
}
```

(activity_main is the same layout as the portrait version, but need to be set again, else the the application puts the portrait version in landscape mode, which I obviously don't want)

**What I want**

I want, when I rotate the display, to have the application switch to the `layout-land` file and after switching, applying some (dynamic) settings to the buttons and stuff.

**What happens**

The new landscaped contentview is set, but the settings for the buttons are not applied, though the `applySettingsToButtons()` method is ran.

**Thoughts**

First I thought mabybe the setContentview is ran in another thread, causing `applySettingsToButtons()` to finish first. But when I put them both in a new thread and run it, the same thing as before happens.

**Question**

How can I apply settings to the buttons and stuff after setting another (or the same) contentview?

Comment: Have you tryed using the debugger and stepping through your code? Are you sure onconfigurationchanged are called? if Yes maybe you need to invalidate the layout.

Comment: yes onConfigurationChanged() is called. ill try the invalide()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you set the XML again via `(setcontentview)` in `configurationChange`, initialize the `findviewbyid` button. That should work.

Comment: That indeed works, too bad that is very bad for my performance, as i need to do controller = new Controller(this), and the controller initializes all Buttons and controls. And thats about 200. But it'll have to do.

Comment: @ChristiaandeJong But you must remember that your references is to the old view in the old activity/fragment and they are not valid after a configuration change.

Comment: As this is the accepted answer, please review my edits for correctness and make any adjustments as needed.